# Graphql query field is returning null

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using expressjs and apollo-server-express. I'm trying to set up a query in graphql to return a product from my database. The problem is that the results never show up in graphql, but when I console log `resultsArr` the results show up fine. Just to note the `resultsArr` is an array of objects.

Express:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Search {
    brand: String
    title: String
    url: String
    thumbnail: String
  }

  type Query {
    results(query: String!): Search
  }
`;  

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    results: (parent, args) => {
      const queries = [
        {
          indexName: 'products',
          query: args.query,
          params: {
            hitsPerPage: 1,
          },
        },
       //
      ];

     return AlgoliaClient.multipleQueries(queries).then(({ results }) => {
        // Store Results
        const resultsArr = [];
        results.forEach((item) => {
          resultsArr.push(item.hits[0]);
        });
        
        // console logging this shows the products
        return resultsArr;
      });
    },
  },
};
```

and my query the graphql playground is:

```
query Search {
  results(query: "Test product") {
    title
  }
}
```

The problem is when I console log resultsArr the products show up no problem, however when it try it though the query I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "results": {
      "title": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `results(query: String!): [Search]`

Comment: bruh that solved it. Thank you.